# netcat to capture ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet, netcat

How can I make sure the result of the following command:

```
nc eth0 &> capture.txt
```

would capture the data + errors transmitted via eth0?

Comment: you want `tcpdump` not `nc`, and it's `-i eth0`

Comment: @Creek please post that as an answer.

Comment: nc will not serve the purpose at all? what if i can not install tcpdump, am i stuck then?

Comment: @Sean not necessarily, you can create an iptables LOG rule which will log high level packet info to syslog

Answer (score 7):

you want `tcpdump` not `nc`, and the syntax would be

```
tcpdump -i eth0
```

`netcat` is only for basic TCP/IP testing.  `tcpdump` utilizes the `libpcap` library which allows for lowlevel interactions with packets and the likes

Answer (score 2):

You should use `tcpdump` with the `-w` switch.

```
tcpdump -i INTERFACE -w FILENAME
```

Replace INTERFACE with the interface you want to listen and FILENAME with the location of the file to which you need to capture the output.